# Which toolbar does Delphi XE2 use for the project manager?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, toolbar

In my own projects I'd like to use the same type of toolbar that the Delphi XE2 IDE uses for the Project Manager: with icons and the option to show a caption for each icon. I don't need drag/dock functionality. Is there a standard component in Delphi XE2 that accomplishes this?

Thanks!

Comment: As per Spy++ that's a `TToolBar`.

Comment: A screen capture of what you're looking for might be nice for future readers of this question.

Comment: Luckily RRUZ provided that below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The project manager uses a [TToolbar](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TToolBar).

[image]

Comment: Awesome, why didn't I think of that? :-)